# Failed to upload photos on FaceBook 2022 using .send_keys() with selenium python

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to upload or post a image on facebook with selenium and python
[image]

for that i tryed with this
This is the path of the section "Add Photos/Videos":

post=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0_fQ"]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjdzh.jpg)/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjdzh.jpg)/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjdzh.jpg)/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjdzh.jpg)/div[2]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjdzh.jpg)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjdzh.jpg)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjdzh.jpg)/div/div')
post.send_keys("G:\PY SCRIPTS\IMAGES\img.png")

apparently this worked in 2020, by now the structure of Facebook changed and i have this error:
ElementNotInteractableException

Comment: Then you need to change the selector to match what it is today. Also be aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to interact with the website automatically. You have to use the API. So if you get banned don't be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

if you use free fb It's easier
[free fb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZWYj.png)

```
post=driver.find_element_by_name("view_post").click() 
post.send_keys(r"G:\PY SCRIPTS\IMAGES\img.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath worked for me trying to upload a video:

```py
element = bot.find_element(By.XPATH, '//form[contains(@method, "POST")]//input[contains(@accept, "video")]')
```

I'll try the API anyway cause I don't wanna get banned.